# Can't access printer shared on a Domain Controller - Logon unsuccessful

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, network-printer

I recently setup a Windows Server 2003 R2 machine to be a domain controller, kind of to experiment with that whole concept. Originally, it was sharing a printer attached to it to my home's workgroup, although it had been awhile since I had used it.

Now, I'm trying to access that printer from a computer that's in the workgroup, but not the domain. I'm trying to re-add it on this computer (which is running Windows Vista Ultimate x64 SP2), and I can't seem to log onto the "Everyone" builtin account like I used to.

I'm assuming that this is some sort of security policy that was brought in by the Domain Controller role, although I can't seem to fix it.

I went into the Default Domain Policy and changed the Allow log on locally policy, and added the Administrators and Everyone groups/users, although I still can't log on from the Vista computer, saying that I'm giving an incorrect Username/password. (For the username, I'm specifying the machine name of the server, then a back slash, and then "Everyone".)

Can anyone tell me what else it is that I have to do?

Comment: Whoops, solved it myself... Posting answer in 7 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, fixed it my self.

Turns out I have to use the Guest account instead. Since it's disabled by default, I had to change the security policy(ies) to enable it. For some reason, on my computer, I have to change two identical policies in different editors to achieve anything.

So, I went into Domain Controller Security Policy **and** Domain Security Policy (anyone care to explain why I need to change both?), then I went to Local Policies > Security Options > Accounts: Guest account status, I checked the check box, and hit Enable. Then after applying, I was able to access the printer.

Hope this helps. I'm still confused as to why two identical security policies needed to be changed.